# Query with sum and join

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have 2 tabels and want to have the sum of one column from table `belegpos`.
With this query it works good, when in `artikel` is only one row with modell.
When there are 2 rows with the same model it takes the sum x2 ( or by 3 rows x3)

```
select bp.modell,sum(bp.quantity) 
from belegpos as bp 
join artikel on bp.modell=artikel.modell 
where  artikel.status=0 
group by bp.modell ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EXISTS` instead of a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT modell, SUM(quantity) 
FROM belegpos AS bp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM artikel 
              WHERE bp.modell = artikel.modell AND artikel.status=0)
GROUP BY bp.modell;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery with distinct instead:

```
select bp.modell,sum(bp.quantity) 
from belegpos as bp 
join (SELECT distinct a.modell from artikel a where a.status=0) a1
  on bp.modell=a1.modell 
group by bp.modell ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select bp.modell,count(bp.quantity) 
from belegpos as bp 
join artikel on bp.modell=artikel.modell 
where  artikel.status=0 
group by bp.modell ;
```